# Saving an android camera2 image to lossless PNG

Tags: android, kotlin, android-camera, android-camera2, rawimage

I'm trying to save android.hardware.camera2 images to a lossless format.

I've got it working for JPEG (lossy) and DMG (raw, but huge and hard to work with) using scrounged bits of code:

```
private fun save(image: Image, captureResult: TotalCaptureResult) {
    val fileWithoutExtension = File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM), "myimage_${System.currentTimeMillis()}")
    val file: File = when (image.format) {
        ImageFormat.JPEG -> {
            val buffer = image.planes[0].buffer
            val bytes = ByteArray(buffer.remaining())
            buffer.get(bytes)
            val file = File("$fileWithoutExtension.jpg")
            file.writeBytes(bytes)
            file
        }
        ImageFormat.RAW_SENSOR -> {
            val dngCreator = DngCreator(mode.characteristics, captureResult)
            val file = File("$fileWithoutExtension.dmg")
            FileOutputStream(file).use { os ->
                dngCreator.writeImage(os, image)
            }
            file
        }
        else -> TODO("Unsupported image format: ${image.format}")
    }
    Log.i(TAG, "Wrote image:${file.canonicalPath} ${file.length() / 1024}k")
    image.close() // necessary when taking a few shots
}
```

but what I'm stuck on is replacing that RAW_SENSOR section with something that saves to a more reasonable PNG.  Is it

1. a bad idea because RAW_SENSOR is so different than a normal image format that I'd have to go through too much pain to convert it?
2. a bad idea because I should have set the upstream capture to capture something more reasonable like FLEX_RGB_888?
3. a good idea because there is some silly mistake in the following code? (which dies with `Buffer not large enough for pixels at android.graphics.Bitmap.copyPixelsFromBuffer(Bitmap.java:593)`

my attempt:

```
fun writeRawImageToPng(image: Image, pngFile: File) {
    Bitmap.createBitmap(image.width, image.height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888).let { latestBitmap->
        latestBitmap.copyPixelsFromBuffer(image.planes[0].buffer!!)
        ByteArrayOutputStream().use { baos ->
            latestBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, baos)
            pngFile.writeBytes(baos.toByteArray())
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you find any solution for it?

Comment: @Vikalp nope no good options. :(

Answer (score 2):

[RAW_SENSOR](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/ImageFormat.html#RAW_SENSOR) is really difficult. The specs tell us that the parameters of the underlying Bayer mosaic can be retrieved from the `CameraDevice`, but there is no public API to convert it into `Bitmap`.

At any rate, there is no advantage requesting this tricky format if your goal is to convert it to 8-bit per channel bitmap.

Furthermore, an `ARGB_8888` bitmap for captured image may be huge, and cause out-of-memory if you are not sufficiently careful.

Answer (score 2):

You want to capture data in the YUV_420_888 format; that's what the JPEG compressor starts with in any case.

You'll have to convert that to an RGB Bitmap yourself, however - there's no convenience method for that.